# Insert text at cursor position in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a textarea that I would like to insert text into at the cursor position when a user clicks a button.  Does anyone know how to go about that?

Comment: When you click a button you move the focused element so there is no cursor in the text anymore. So you would have to track the last location of the cursor and then just set the value of the text area to be the current value + the extra text at the location of the last know cursor position.

Answer (score 15):

Qwertie is of course right. 
Anyway, if you want to insert a given string into a textarea at the cursor position
you could use a function like this:

```
 insertMyText = e => {
      let textToInsert = " this is the inserted text "
      let cursorPosition = e.target.selectionStart
      let textBeforeCursorPosition = e.target.value.substring(0, cursorPosition)
      let textAfterCursorPosition = e.target.value.substring(cursorPosition, e.target.value.length)
      e.target.value = textBeforeCursorPosition + textToInsert + textAfterCursorPosition
    }
```

and:

```
<textarea onClick={this.insertMyText}>bla bla bla bla</textarea>
```